# KVM bridge network guest not getting ip

Tags: linux, qemu

I'm trying to bridge my ubuntu vm to my network I make bridge connection throw nmtui

[image]

[image]

This is my ubuntu network setting:
[image]

/etc/qemu/bridge.conf

```
allow virbr0
allow nm-bridge
```

my machine:
[image]

i try to restart dhcpcd but nothing changed

Comment: what's the output of `brctl show`

Comment: @JaromandaX
`bridge name bridge id  STP enabled interfaces
nm-bridge  8000.eee7b00a3539 yes  
virbr0  8000.5254002d9f07 yes  vnet1
`

Comment: can't read that